# how filter or show last date of each month between two dates in adoquery delphi

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I need help, how to filter or show last date of each month between two dates (datetimepicker) in adoquery (datebase ms.access) delphi,
for example : date1 = 14/01/2023 and date2= 03/03/2023,
calculate have 3 month, month1 month2 month3,

month1 have date : 14/01/2023, 15/01/2023, 16/01/2023
month2 have date : 01/02/2023, 02/02/2023, 03/02/2023, 04/02/2023
month3 have date : 01/03/2023, 02/03/2023, 03/03/2023

I want filter last date like :

month1 : 16/01/2023

month2 : 04/02/2023

month3 : 03/03/2023

I hope any one can help, thank u

Comment: `select month(date_field) as mm, max(date_field) as last_date from table group by month(date_field) order by month(date_field)`

Comment: And if you want to limit the dates `select month(date_field) as mm, max(date_field) as last_date  from table where date_field between date1 and date2 group by month(date_field) order by month(date_field)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query syntax shown earlier, which is handy if you're using data from forms specified as dates, and stored as strings in the DB.

Alternatively you can use code easily because TDate and TDateTime are simply floating-point numbers where the whole part is days and the fractional part is seconds or msecs within the day. You can easily add, subtract, and compare these values without having to resort to how they are displayed in a form or query using a date and/or time format. (Although, comparing floating-point numbers using = and <> is ill-advised.)

I don't know what format or data type ADO uses to save dates, but you should be able to easily convert them back and forth between strings and TDate values.

Keep in mind that it takes very little code to work with floating-point numbers, while working with strings takes quite a bit more processing overhead. If it's a large table that saves dates as strings, consider converting the string dates to TDate -> integer, or just use a Julian date (integer value), in another field/column.

If you're only looking for dates, then just use the whole part with relational operators, possibly by adding 0.5 before converting to an integer using the Floor method first.